# Problem with the button of cookies bar created by the ruby gem named 'cookies_eu'

Tags: ruby, cookies, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I use Ruby 2.6.5 and Rails 5.2.4.1
I want to use the ruby gem cookies_eu : https://github.com/infinum/cookies_eu

All works correctly, but I have a problem.
The cookie bar doesn't want to disappear definitely when I click on the 'OK' button.

I have the same problem in production and development environment. When I click on the cookies_eu button "OK", the cookie bar disappears as expected. But if I go to another page of my website, sometimes the cookie bar appears again.

What is the problem ? I have already ask this question on the github page of the gem for 2 months, but there is no answer right now.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue with gem 'cookies_eu'.
To resolve this i tried another gem, https://github.com/frizbee/cookieconsent.

Comment: Thanks Shivam, I will see it.